# What test to use on proportional tables?

Tags: chi-squared-test, matrix

I have two matrices in which the sum of all the values in each row sums up to 1. In R they can be obtained by:

```
m1 <-matrix(runif(5*6), ncol=6)
m2 <-matrix(runif(5*6), ncol=6)
m1 <- round(prop.table(m1,1),2)
m2 <- round(prop.table(m2,1),2)
```

I would like to test for changes in the proportions in each row between the two matrices.

For example, if the first row of the first matrix is `0,0,0,0.5,0.5` and the first row of the second matrix is `0.2,0,0,0.1,0.7`, I would like to know if this difference is significant or not.

I have tried by testing chi square and using the first matrix as probability for the second one:

```
chisq.test(x=as.vector(m2), p=as.vector(m1)/sum(m1))
```

But: first, in my matrices I have many zeros and the test fails; second, apparently it is not correct to use chi square but on counts, and here I deal with proportions.

Is there any test I can use?

Comment: One cannot make a rational choice of tests without knowing what these data *mean*. In a typical application the proportions are obtained by dividing counts of observations by their totals: and a critically important piece of information is contained in those total values.  And if your data are not derived from counts, then equivalent information about their inherent variability is necessary in order to proceed.

Comment: Thanks whuber. The situation is tricky, because the two matrices are about the same objects (media articles) described by the same two variables (theme and media). In the first matrix the cells contain raw counts of articles. In the second matrix, the cells contain the sum of the weights of each article. My research is about whether this weighting affects the equilibrium of the first matrix. I do have absolute counts, but they differ in magnitude from the first to the second matrix, while still being about the same objects.

Comment: If you want to choose an appropriate procedure, you will need to characterize your data sufficiently clearly so that one can adopt a relevant probability model for them.  Such a characterization would likely include information about what measurements were made as well as any assumptions about the statistical behavior of the data.

Comment: Ok I'll add the infos to my question, I thought that going too much into detail would on the contrary be too specific and I tried to produce a general question